# In Ubuntu, how do I make an alias inside a bash for loop?

Tags: bash, variables, ubuntu, for-loop, alias

I have a script to help me with testing concurrency.  I use screen to run a bunch of things at once.  But within all that, I can't figure out how make an alias (or function?) using the for $i variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
# alias p='. ./p.sh'

# Run a bunch of apps in separate screens.

export NUM_MUS=3
for (( i = 1; i <= $NUM_MUS; ++i ))
do
   echo $i
   cd ~/mutest/mu$i
   screen -mS mu$i -h 10000 ./app

# How do I make an alias to let me easily access each screen?
# None of these work.
#
#   alias mu$i='screen -dr mu$i'
#   eval
#   function mu$i () { screen -dr mu$i }

   # ^AD to get out
done

# Have a way of killing them all.

function mustop ()
   {
   for (( i = 1; i <= $NUM_MUS; ++i ))
   do
      screen -r mu$i -X quit
   done
   screen -ls
   }
```

Please note that I am NOT asking about taking parameters.  I don't want parameters ... unless there IS a way to make it work with parameters?

...

Okay, I can add this line, and it'll work "good enough"

```
function mu { screen -dr mu$1 }
```

But it still doesn't answer my question of using for loop variables to make a buncha aliases/functions.  I'm not saying that's this is smartest way to do things, but if I *did* want to do this, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are expanded inside double quotes, not inside single quotes.

```
alias mu$i="screen -dr mu$i"
```

Also, make sure you run the script using `source scriptname`, so the aliases will be defined in your original shell, not just the shell executing the script.

Comment: Well THAT solved it!  How come that was never mentioned in any of the pages and pages explaining how to use alias that I waded through?

Comment: It's not specific to aliases, it's true for strings everywhere in the shell.

Comment: Huh.  First time I've been made aware of that.  So it's just like PHP then.

Comment: It's the other way around. I think PHP copied it from Perl, which copied it from the shell.